# Airflow - coordinating DAGs with different schedules

Tags: architecture, airflow

We have some DAGs that perform various sorts of data processing. We anticipate that as this system grows, there will be more DAGs from a number of different internal teams, and some of them may have dependencies on the DAGs & data of other teams. We were thinking of having one single "main scheduler" DAG to coordinate all of these inter-DAG dependencies using TriggerDagRunOperators, something like this:

```py
dag_1 = TriggerDagRunOperator(trigger_dag_id = "dag_1_id", ...)
dag_2 = TriggerDagRunOperator(trigger_dag_id = "dag_2_id", ...)
dag_3 = TriggerDagRunOperator(trigger_dag_id = "dag_3_id", ...)
dag_4 = TriggerDagRunOperator(trigger_dag_id = "dag_4_id", ...)
dag_5 = TriggerDagRunOperator(trigger_dag_id = "dag_5_id", ...)

# dag_1 has no dependencies, and nothing depends on it. Easy!
dag_1
# The team that built dag_3 rely on outputs from dag_2
dag_2 >> dag_3
# dag_5 depends on dag_2 and dag_4.
# The catch: dag_2 should only run once per day, but the team that built
# dag_5 would like their dag to run every 20 minutes - it has other external
# dependencies that change much more frequently that the outputs of dag_2.
dag_5 << [dag_2, dag_4]
```

One issue I'm not sure of is how to resolve scheduling. Some of the existing DAGs only need to run once per day, but there may be others that need to run more frequently.

My thought is: remove specific schedules from the DAGs and use time-based sensors to execute DAGs from the main scheduler DAG. My only concern with this idea is that the main scheduler DAG would have to run as frequently as the most frequent child-DAG that it triggers, and this feels "wrong", somehow.

I've never tried to build anything quite like this, so I guess I'm just looking for a sanity-check on this idea, or a suggestion of a better way to do this.

(Using Airflow 2.2.3 with Google Cloud Composer)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for "data-aware scheduling", first introduced in Airflow 2.4.0: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html. This feature enables you to run DAGs based on an update of data, instead of a schedule based on time. For example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow.datasets import Dataset
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def producing_dag_1():
    @task(outlets=Dataset("s3://example/data/one"))
    def upload_data_to_s3():
        print("... Upload data to s3 ...")

    upload_data_to_s3()


@dag(start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def producing_dag_2():
    @task(outlets=Dataset("s3://example/data/two"))
    def upload_data_to_s3():
        print("... Upload data to s3 ...")

    upload_data_to_s3()


@dag(
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    schedule=[Dataset("s3://example/data/one"), Dataset("s3://example/data/two")],
)
def consuming_dag():
    @task
    def generate_report():
        print("... Use datasets one and two to generate report ...")

    generate_report()


producing_dag_1()
producing_dag_2()
consuming_dag()
```

Here we have three DAGs: `producing_dag_1`, `producing_dag_2`, and `consuming_dag`. Note the producing_dags would still run on a schedule. Tasks in the producing_dags have an `outlet` specified; this indicates those tasks produce a piece of data, for example:

```py
outlets=Dataset("s3://example/data/one")
```

DAGs that depend on the availability of data can now schedule on `Datasets`, instead of time:

```py
schedule=[Dataset("s3://example/data/one"), Dataset("s3://example/data/two")],
```

This would trigger the DAG consuming_dag after an update on both Datasets `s3://example/data/one` and `s3://example/data/two`.

To inspect dataset-based dependencies visually, there's a Dataset view in the Airflow UI ([https://[airflowhost]/datasets](https://%5Bairflowhost%5D/datasets)):

[image]

Here you see the two producing DAGs, the datasets they produce, and the DAGs (consuming_dag) that depend on those datasets.

For more information about datasets and data-aware scheduling, see:

- https://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-2.4.0
- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html
- https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-datasets

Comment: This looks very cool! Alas, we're using Google Cloud Composer for our Airflow environment, with Airflow 2.2.3.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dag like that can complicate the development especially for:

- dealing with the different schedules
- calculating the data interval

Instead, you can create each dag with its own schedule, and use a custom sensor to check if all the runs between the data interval dates are finished successfully (or skipped if you want):

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.utils.context import Context
from airflow.utils.session import provide_session
from airflow.utils.state import State


class ExternalRunSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    """
    A custom sensor to poke external DagRuns
    """

    template_fields = [
        "external_dag_id",
    ]

    def __init__(
        self,
        external_dag_id,
        expected_runs_count,
        allowed_states=None,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        self.external_dag_id = external_dag_id
        self.expected_runs_count = expected_runs_count
        self.allowed_states = allowed_states or [State.SUCCESS, State.SKIPPED]
        super(ExternalRunSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @provide_session
    def poke(self, context: Context, session=None):
        start_date = context["data_interval_start"]
        end_date = context["data_interval_end"]

        runs_count = session.query(
            func.count()
        ).filter(
            DagRun.dag_id == self.external_dag_id,
            DagRun.execution_date >= start_date,
            DagRun.execution_date < end_date,
            DagRun.state.in_(self.allowed_states)
        ).scalar()

        return runs_count == self.expected_runs_count

# in the hourly dag which should wait the 3 runs of the dag scheduled every 20 minutes
sensor = ExternalRunSensor(external_dag_id="dag_20_min", expected_runs_count=3)
```

You can also improve it and try to auto calculate the `expected_runs_count` based on schedule interval

Comment: I'll have to look into this more but it sounds promising!